# Error occurring when generating random string, and using when sending an email

Tags: python, django

I am writing an endpoint in my api where users can reset their passwords. I use the python library smtp to send an email to the user with a code. This code is a simple string.

I randomly generate this string, and send it as the content for the email.

However when I send a request to the endpoint, The error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'** 
    occurs.

Here is my endpoint code:

```
code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(8))
content = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format('Your code to reset your password:', code)
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login(os.environ.get('email'), os.environ.get('password'))
mail.sendmail(os.environ.get('email'), user.email, content)
mail.close()
hashedReset = make_password(code)
user.resetCode = hashedReset
user.save()
return JsonResponse({'message': 'An email has successfully been sent to the email paired with this account.'}, status=200)
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    resetCode = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

When I print the **code** variable, a random string is displayed, therefore that isn't the issue.

Anyone know what the issue is? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the version of Python being used, check your `User` model object and ensure it has a `__unicode__` method that returns something other than `None`. If you're using Python 3, this is how your object is turned in to a string representation (in Python 2, this used to be `__str__`, so make sure it's a string value here.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the response. What is the role of the **__unicode__**  method, and what should I set the return value as?

Comment: I have also edited my original post by adding the **User** model code in.

Comment: Also I am using the latest version of python (version 3.8)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. `__unicode__` is how Python (3.x, this used to be `__str__` in Python2) serializes an object. Think of it as a `toSting()` method, so its return value should be ... whatever you want it to be, just not `None` :).